# What makes the differences between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar

Context 1

A: What should we do on your day off?

B: If it stops raining tonight, we **can** play basketball in the park tomorrow. The ground will be dry enough.

Context 2

A: I want to play some sports.

B: If it stops raining tonight, we **can** play basketball in the park tomorrow. The ground will be dry enough.

I think in context 1 "can" sounds okay while in context 2 "can" should be replaced with "will be able to."

I don't know what makes the difference. Is it because context one sounds like a suggestion of an activity they will have the opportunity to do while context two sounds like a mere description of the gaining of the ability to play basketball in the park?

Comment: (2) certainly doesn't _need_ to be changed to 'be able to', although it _could_ be.

Comment: Both your sentences are exactly the same. So?

Answer (score 3):

Both sound ok to me. In the first example "could" would be better than "can" but "can" isn't wrong. In the second case B is stating a fact in response to a straightforward statement, so "can" sounds fine although "could" would be as good. In both cases "could" emphasises the conditionality, which is implied by the context anyway.

Using "will be able to" to change to a future tense is unnecessary in either case and adds nothing and would sound over wordy in speech.

Comment: Does this one in bold also make sense in the following context?

A: I have to work overtime tomorrow so I think we will need to order pizza for dinner. 
B: No worries. I will be home early to pick up Jimmy. **If you leave some ingredients in the refrigerator tonight, I can cook tomorrow night.**

Comment: @Skywarrior - yes that works fine, Again, changing to "will be able to" adds nothing. One way to think of it is that although "tomorrow night" is in the future your ability to cook at that time already exists in the present.